# Create PayPal sandbox accounts - something went wrong

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Spent the last few days trying to create sandbox accounts from within PayPal's developer dashboard. Selected Sandbox Accounts -> Create Account. Filled out the form with different setups; starting balances between 1 - 5000, different emails, different passwords, everything.

Before clicking Create Account, there is an error saying "We're sorry, something went wrong while fetching test accounts. Please try again". After trying to create an account, I get the same error, plus a new one saying "We're sorry, something went wrong during account creation. Please try again."

Not sure what to do after clearing cache/trying different browsers.

Comment: Same issue for me today as well trying to get it to work, it wont show existing accoutns or let me create new acounts

Comment: Looks like a problem on the developer site since last night. Still not fixed

Comment: Is it fixed today? I'm getting this error though

Comment: I'm getting this error too (October 2018) - has anyone figured out how to get this working?

Comment: It seems as though it's a generic error on their part. If you contact support and give it a couple of days they seem to correct whatever is going wrong.